# How to send multiple drafts from Outlook 2003

Tags: vb.net, outlook

Outlook wont let me send multiple drafts at the same time. Is there an easy way to send multiple drafts at once in outlook? without having to open each one individually?

From what i've read, seen and tried; this is not possible from within outlook itself, and thus a programming solution would be required, probably some VB script

Comment: +1 close, not programming related.

Comment: I would say it is, because it's not possible to do this via outlook itself. A programming solution is the only way i can see this being solved.

Comment: @spence - Then you need to specify that you are looking for a programmatic solution to the problem within the body of your question. Right now it just sounds like you want to know if anyone can provide a how-to with Outlook.

Comment: fair enough, i wanted to leave it ambiguous, just in case someone had a trivial soloution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, i found a bit of VB that does it:

```
`Public Sub SendDrafts()

Dim lDraftItem As Long
Dim myOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim myFolders As Outlook.Folders
Dim myDraftsFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

'Send all items in the "Drafts" folder that have a "To" address filled
'in.

'Setup Outlook

Set myOutlook = Outlook.Application
Set myNameSpace = myOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set myFolders = myNameSpace.Folders


'Set Draft Folder.  This will need modification based on where it's
'being run.

Set myDraftsFolder = myFolders("$MAILBOX").Folders("$DRAFTS")

'Loop through all Draft Items

For lDraftItem = myDraftsFolder.Items.Count To 1 Step -1

'Check for "To" address and only send if "To" is filled in.

If Len(Trim(myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).To)) > 0 Then

'Send Item

myDraftsFolder.Items.Item(lDraftItem).Send

End If
Next lDraftItem

'Clean-up

Set myDraftsFolder = Nothing
Set myNameSpace = Nothing
Set myOutlook = Nothing

End Sub
```

just replace $MAILBOX with your mailbox name and $DRAFTS with the name of your drafts folder.
This has been personnaly tested and seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not very different from author's answer, but still:

```
Sub SendDrafts()
  Dim ns As NameSpace
  Dim drafts As MAPIFolder
  Dim Item As MailItem

  Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set drafts = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts) ' 16
  For Each Item In drafts.Items
    'Item.Send
  Next
End Sub
```

Please be careful as it really sends all emails in your default draft folder. After uncommenting the send line. `Dim` lines to allow for autocompletion when inside Outlook macro editor.

Answer (score 0):

A useful version, which I just tested in Outlook 2000:

Drag the emails you wish to send to the Outbox.  They won't be sent automatically, but using this version of the prior posting sends them:

```
Sub SendOutbox()
  Dim ns As NameSpace
  Dim outbox As MAPIFolder
  Dim Item As MailItem

  Set ns = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set outbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox) ' 16
  For Each Item In outbox.Items
    Item.Send
  Next
End Sub
```

That way, you can be selective.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can write a macro or add-in to do that.